# How do I specify a list of required xml child elements that DONT need to be in sequence?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation

The following xml validates against the supplied xsd document. However when i start removing elements like  from the xml it STILL validates!?

How do I write an xsd that forces the inclusion of elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Video>
  <Title>
  </Title>
  <Description>
  </Description>
  <Contributor>
  </Contributor>
  <Subject>
  </Subject>
</Video>
```

Then I have the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="UploadXSD"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/UploadXSD.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/UploadXSD.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/UploadXSD.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Video">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Title" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Description" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Contributor" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Subject" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your targetNamespace in the xsd should match the namespace of the xml you are trying to validate, i.e.

```
<Video xmlns="http://tempuri.org/UploadXSD.xsd">
  <Title>
  </Title>
  <Description>
  </Description>
  <Contributor>
  </Contributor>
  <Subject>
  </Subject>
</Video>
```

Comment: That's *one* of the problems in the code. It's nothing to do with the question in the title though. @Ryan Brunner has answered the question asked. A sequence has to be in order.

Comment: Yes, but that's the reason the expected validation errors mentioned weren't appearing.  I agree that Ryan's answer correctly answers the title question, but it doesn't address the overall problem mentioned in the body.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `xs:all` as opposed to `xs:sequence`, the elements may appear in any order. There are some additional restrictions - for example, elements can not be specified multiple times using `all` (I'm not sure if you intend that usage, your schema would currently allow that.)